# How can I support Birdhouse Gourds without nailing anything to my fence?

Tags: vines, support, fence, trellis, gourds

I have birdhouse gourd vines growing up my fence. I started with a river cane trellis pushed into the soil in the tubs the gourds are growing in. This initial trellis can not support the new growth. I don't want to use any more river cane. What is the best way to trellis my gourds to the left and right along the fence without using nails?

[image: Birdhouse gourd vine and original river cane trellis]

Comment: You can tie it to the fence with twine, or rope.

Answer (score 3):

Trellis netting.

[image: trellis net on fence]

Picture is from Gardener's Edge (not affiliated, might have bought something from them once, I don't recall for certain) and could practically be your fence. The 6" string mesh can be hooked between the boards on top to hold it.

Beware of tangles. I thought this stuff was a much better idea before I got some and had to detangle it after the first use and storing away for the winter. It can get into fiendish knots.